# How to update libpango and install Cairo in Ubuntu?

Tags: php, gtk, cairo, pango

I want to install "php gtk", but I get the following error message:

```
`libgtk2.0-dev : Depends: libpango1.0-dev (>= 1.20) but it is not going to be installed
```

I downloaded the latest pango from [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/pango/1.36/pango-1.36.0.tar.xz).

When I ran the command: `./configure`, it gave me the following error message:

```
checking for HARFBUZZ... no no  
checking for CoreText availability... no 
checking for CAIRO... no no  
configure: error: Could not enable any backends. Must have at least one backend to build Pango
```

I tried to install `php_cairo`, but it gives an error too:

```
checking for Cario... not found 
configure: error: Oops! No Cairo detected in the system
```

How can I update `libpango`, and install Cairo? Thanks.

Comment: How are you installing "php gtk"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install cairo by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install cairo-dock
```

For other part I am working myself. Just read INSTALL. I have found pango-1.34.1 package from web and I try to install myself.